# Which version of Javascript supports exactly equals?

Tags: javascript

My current version of Eclipse (Kepler) shows my projects as having version 1.0 and complains about the === exactly equals. Which version of JS supports ===?

Thanks

Comment: You're not trying to use it in Java mode, are you?

Comment: Just on a side note, while Eclipse started as a great project with big momentum and excitement, unfortunately for various reasons it has become a messed up, slow, behemoth IDE that is broken from upside down. I highly recommend IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 4):

[Javascript 1.3 added the strict equality operators.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) However, Javascript 1.3 is hopelessly out of date. Any modern web browser will have support.

Comment: Yeap. As can be seen [here (PDF)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf), the first edition of ECMAScript didn't have the `===` operator.

Comment: Good to know, hopefully nobody it's on JavaScript 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your replies

I'm not using === in Java, I have a project that is using it in their JS. when I imported the project into Eclipse there were errors in the JS. I know the project works. I may purchase a copy of IntelliJ v13 is the latest I believe.

Most Contracts I'v been on make use of Eclipse and it default to 1.0. I'm may look into adding the JsDT and see if that helps.